# Simple search form Error Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, search

I am trying to add a simple search form in layout in my application.It should search products by title or description.I created partials, methods in Products model, but when I try to put render _search into application.html.erb, it crashes the application with "We're sorry, but something went wrong." Any ideas how to fix that?
Files:

app/models/product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
#...
def self.search(search)
    search_condition = "%" + search + "%"
    find(:all, :conditions => ['title LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?', search_condition, search_condition])
  end

  #...
```

app/controllers/products_controller.rb

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
#...
 def search
      @products = Product.search params[:search]
  end
#...
```

app/views/products/_search.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag :controller => 'products', :action => 'search', :method => 'get' do %>
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :id => 'search_field' %>
      <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %> 
      <%= link_to_function "Clear", "$('search_field').clear()" %>
<% end %>
```

app/views/products/_search_results.html.erb

```
    <ul>
     <% @products.each do |product| %>
 <li><%= link_to product.title, :action => 'show', :id => product.id  %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
```

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <%# Это файл макета-шаблона для всех веб-страниц%>
<html>



<head>

  <title>MyGift.com</title> 
...
<div id="search">
   <%= render :partial => "products/search" %>
</div>

...
```

The error from server console:
 Rendered store/index.html.erb within layouts/application (9.5ms)
  Rendered products/_search.html.erb (0.9ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 499ms

Comment: run your server in development mode and see the error log. or paste your production log

Comment: your search action in the products controller isn't rendering/redirecting

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in your code. Your code should run absolutely fine. I guess you are missing some logs info. Its better to share screen shot of your log file so that we can see if any valuable info is missing.

Comment: Do you mean file log/test.log ? or log/development.log ?

Comment: development.log file or screenshot of your console when you get this error.